# in c# when returning a string from a function does the memory get freed?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

This is what I mean:

```
class mycalss
{
   string myfunc()
   {
      string str="hello";
      return str;
   }
}
...
static void main()
{
   string str2;
   str2=myfunc();
   ...
   ...
}
```

In this case is there a risk that the garbage collector might delete the contents of str2 because str went out of scope?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. The garbage detector will see that str2 has a reference to the data, and it won't be collected.

Answer (score 7):

No, there's no risk here. The reference will be returned, and if the garbage collector runs it will be able to see the reference in `main`, so it won't free the string.

Note that even when the string *is* eligible for garbage collection, it won't be freed immediately - only when the garbage collector next runs (or even later, depending on what generation it ends up in).

Note that the garbage collector *can* collect objects which won't be used any more, even if there's a variable still in scope - so long as it knows that the variable won't be read again:

```
object x = new object();
Console.WriteLine(x);
// Lots more code not touching x
// The object could be collected at any time here
```

Answer (score 7):

str and str2 are both references to one (string) object. The garbage collector will only reclaim objects that have zero remaining references.

Answer (score 0):

No. As long as the reference to the same string is held, by str2 in this case. The GC will not collect it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the garbage collector will not delete the contents of the string, for two reasons:

- You have a reference to the string, and as long as there are any active references to an object the garbage collector won't delete it.
- It's a string literal, so it's a constant in the assembly. It's created when the assembly is loaded and removed when the assembly is removed (i.e. when the application ends). The garbage collector will never delete a string literal.

Answer (score -1):

Incorrect answer:

String is immutable, which I believe means that in your example, you will have a new copy of your string in memory, so when str is cleaned up, str2 has its own data.

Jon Skeet's clarification:

No - they're both references to the same string object. It copies the **reference** not the string.

Comment: No - they're both references to the same string object. It copies the *reference* not the string.

Answer (score -2):

You'll be fine.  Strings are value types.  Normally when you return a value type you actually get a *copy* of the object.  So when the `str` variable goes out of scope and is collected you're `str2` variable will be just fine.

Now, because these are *strings* we're talking about here and not just any run-of-the-mill value type there are a few other things going on as well.  Your "hello" string is most likely placed by the compiler into a string table and your string variables will be *references* to that same entry in the table, to avoid keeping around lots of copies of the same string.

Either way, don't worry about it being collected.

Comment: String isn't a value type. It's a reference type. You don't get a copy of the object, you get a copy of the *reference*.

Comment: (You're right about the literal being interned, admittedly - but I'd imagine that in the real code it isn't a literal being returned.)